# proof $\{a_n\}$ is bounded (check)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$a_n=\sup \{x_k:k\ge n\}$. $\{x_k:k\ge n+1\}$ is a subset of $\{x_k:k\ge n\}$. Then, $a_n$ is an upper-bound for $\{x_k:k\ge n+1\}$. This implies $\sup\{x_k:k\ge n+1\}=a_{n+1} \le a_n$. Therefore, $a_n$ is monotone decreasing. Let $\limsup x_n =x$. Then, $\lim a_n = x$, which implies that $a_n \ge x$.

Could you check this proof is okay? 
Thank you in advance.

Edit:  I forgot to mention that $x_n$ is bounded.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prove?  You have not shown that $a_n$ is bounded, but it's not.  What if $x_k = k$.  Then $a_n =\infty$ for all $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n$ is monotonically decreasing.

However, we have to be careful that $x$ might be $-\infty$.

$a_n$ is not bounded below if $x_n \to -\infty$.

If $x_n$ is bounded, then $a_n$ is bounded.

Comment: True . I forgot to say $x_n$ is bounded.

Comment: Ah, then it seems fine, in that case, $x$ is finite.